# Django keep me login feature is not working

Tags: django

I want a solution if any anyone can assist me.
When customer will login with keep me login checked then session will not be expire, But if keep me login is not checked then should expire as per bellow mentioned setting.py variable value.

So Now login without checked keep me login is working fine as we have set SESSION_SECURITY_WARN_AFTER and SESSION_SECURITY_EXPIRE_AFTER. And if keep me login is checked, I tried to disable by overriding above variable value or increase expire time using request.session.set_expiry(24*30*3600). But it is not working. Can you anyone advice how can I disable this expire time if keep me login is checked.

settings.py

```
EXPIRE_TIME = 60*10
SESSION_SECURITY_WARN_AFTER = EXPIRE_TIME
SESSION_SECURITY_EXPIRE_AFTER = EXPIRE_TIME + 180
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How did you installed `django-session-security` ? What are the related settings in settings.py file ?

Comment: @user3111381 you have to write a middleware to handle this timeout issue.

Comment: Hi Raja, Vijesh,

Thanks for responding to me. 
Re `What are the related settings in settings.py file`
I added  'session_security.middleware.SessionSecurityMiddleware' in settings.py
in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES. so I think `django-session-security` install is correct. But main problem is I want to override 

`SESSION_SECURITY_WARN_AFTER `
`SESSION_SECURITY_EXPIRE_AFTER`

And I also tried to override these two value by creating a middleware but still it is taking settings.py value.

If you have any idea or any other way to meet the above functionality. Please suggest,

Comment: I followed `http://django-session-security.readthedocs.io/en/latest/full.html`
in all.html javascript code
`var sessionSecurity = new yourlabs.SessionSecurity({
  expireUrl: '{% url 'auth_logout' %}',
                pingUrl: '{% url 'session_security_ping' %}',
                warnAfter: {{ request|warn_after|unlocalize }},
                expireAfter: {{ request|expire_after|unlocalize }},
                confirmFormDiscard: "{% trans 'You have unsaved changes in a form of this page.' %}"
            });` 
warnAfter and expireAfter value always getting from setting.py value.